# Representing byte array as an XSD schema

Tags: xsd, jaxb

What is the best way to represent a byte array as an XSD schema? I have a byte input which I need to parse and to feed to Java objects generated by JAXB out of an XSD schema for future validation. Every piece of information in my input is defined by offset and the length. I would like to attach this information to my elements so I could then read it from generated classes and use for parsing. The only way to attach such additional information to an Element I can think of is representing every Element as a Complex Type and then adding attributes to the complex Element and restrictions – to the simple Element wrapped by this complex Element. The problem with this approach (in addition to the Schema looking messy) is that JAXB will create separate class for every Element (Complex Type). And I will have a lot of fields in my input. :) The second issue is that I will in fact attach attributes and restrictions (which I need for validation) to different elements (wrapped simple element and the complex wrapper). So I will need to find a way to figure out that they in fact represent the same piece of information. I hope all this make sense. :) Basically my question is: can you think of a more elegant way to attach position and length information to an XSD element that represents the corresponding piece of a byte array? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What is the best way to represent a
>   byte array as an XSD schema? I have a
>   byte input which I need to parse and
>   to feed to Java objects generated by
>   JAXB out of an XSD schema for future
>   validation.

JAXB will convert a `byte[]` to/from elements and attributes of type `xsd:base64Binary`.

For information on starting from XML schema see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/05/schema-to-java-xmlmimetype.html

For information on starting from Java classes see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/03/jaxb-web-services-and-binary-data.html

Comment: What is the type of your property a byte[] or an object?

Comment: @Atman - And you want to store all of it, or just a portion of it?

Comment: I want to store several pieces that represent particular values. For instance I want to retrive say "status" that I know is in position 15 and is 5 bytes long. Or something like that.

Comment: The idea is to attach 15 and 5 as attributes and restrictions to my XSD element that represents "status".

Comment: @Atman - Could you post an example of what you would like the class and XML to look like?

Comment: Basically I am trying to create a schema that would result in a class that somehow contains getters for position and length for every element. For example if I define every element in my schema as a complex type and attach attributes as fixed values I'm getting the following getter for the position:

Comment: '    public String getByteOffset() {
        if (byteOffset == null) {
            return "11";
        } else {
            return byteOffset;
        }
    }'

Comment: The problem like I said is that to do that I need a separate class for every field even if this field normally is of simple type. But may be it is not such a big problem.

Comment: @Blaise - I just thought of something. Why can't I store position/length information as default value of a simple element? I can call getter first retrieve my information and then use it to parse my byte array and then call setter with actual value. For validation I can use restrictions imposed on the simple element. I can see only two requirements. I will need to define all my simple elements as xsd:strings and I need to make sure that my "position/length" pair if of length equal to "length". Maybe it's easier than using attributes.

Comment: Nope. Won't work. What is my piece of information is at a position 194 but only one byte long? :) I think I'll go with the attributes. :)